# How to login with different login credentials in Single sign on application

Tags: typescript, authentication, configuration, protractor, single-sign-on

I am working in a project where I need to automate application using protractor type script. When I am accessing the application it is automatically taking the login credentials of the system. But as per my requirement I need to login through the application with generic credentials to integrate with Jenkins. The application we are working is sso application.

Comment: What do you mean by `generic credentials`?

Comment: It's different userid and password to login for the application. Because as per security reasons our login credentials can't be given to Jenkins . So they created some dummy userid and password in database to login to the application .

Comment: How and when those data are created?

Comment: These data has been given by backend for testing purposes.

Comment: Is there an endpoint that returns data eg. recently created user? Is password randomly generated or is there any rule/pattern?

Comment: btw. you can store an envarionment variables with login and password, but I'm not sure is it convinient for you

Comment: Once we open browser and if we send the url  it is automatically login with the userid credentials of the machine . I need to login with different credentials.

Comment: It's not randomly generated . They gave different userid and password who all have access to the application to test it .

Comment: There is no login page in the application

Comment: Can you post some information about the db in your question?  It sounds like you will need to send new credentials to the db and then clear your session data before running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how to "automatically" works login mechanism. So, you can use it.

From my experience you will firstly send API request and make a login with needed credentials. Then you will go to login and system will catch that you have already logged in.